# ScrollView height for 3.5" vs 4" iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a UITableView in a UIViewController which is inside a UINavigationController which is inside a UITabBarController.

When Developing using a 3.5" Simulator and having my storyboard set to 3.5" and everything works fine.

However if I use a 4" simulator, the UITableView ends too short up the screen. And if I do it the other way around the table view ends off the bottom of the screen.

How do I go about correctly sizing my UITableView?

(P.S. I'm not sure it matters, but I'm loading an AdBannerView which goes at the bottom of the screen, so I'm adjusting the contentInset of the UITableView after it is loaded to make space for the AdBannerView, but I don't think that makes a difference to this situation).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add auto layout constraints so that the components are resized according to the desired logic.

Read [Apple's Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) and you'll know everything you need in order to accomplish this.